# Automatic Login to MVC Web App from winform

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have an MVC web app with an API backend. I have an exe which polls the API every x minutes to retrieve some informaton. I have that portion working, however I want to extend this functionality a bit. I want the user to be able to click on the winform that pops up and then have the user automatically be directed to the website to a special page which shows details about the pop up (basically it's retrieving some info of an event)....I can do a simple Process.Start() to the website however the website needs authentication.

The web app has standard OWIN authentication...now my question is how I can automatically have some sort of authentication passed into this Process.Start() where by I can automatically login.

It basically hits an "Account" controller....I was able to simulate what I wanted (automatic authentication) via Postman but it didn't work on the Winform app.

Is there any other way to do this?

I can post some code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When doing things like this in the past I have opted to generate a GUID and place it in my db, then use that GUID with whatever extra information it needs to authenticate my user.  I don't know how this falls into your security requirements however.